# Linking Netlogo and Python over Java Gateway

Tags: python, netlogo

I was trying to connect Python and Netlogo over a java bridge using nl4py. I keep getting an error after trying everything like it is described here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.03292.pdf . I am using MAC and python 2.7.

I also tried doing it without nl4py and straight up using py4j to do it manually. But when I try to call `from py4j.Java_Gateway import Java_Gateway` I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/Machines Model/pythonjavanetlogolink.py", line 1, in <module>
    from py4j.Java_Gateway import Java_Gateway
ImportError: No module named Java_Gateway'
```

```py
import nl4py
import time

nl4py.startServer("/Users/user/Desktop/NetLogo610")

model = "/Users/user/Desktop/Machines Model/ABM4.nlogo"

nl4py.netlogoWorkspaceFactory.deleteAllExistingWorkspaces()

nl4py.netlogoWorkspaceFactory.newNetLogoHeadlessWorkspace()

for workspace in nl4py.netlogoWorkspaceFactory.getAllExistingWorkspaces():
    workspace.openModel(model)

nl4py.netlogoWorkspaceFactory.deleteAllExistingWorkspaces()

nl4py.stopServer()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/Machines Model/python_link.py", line 13, in <module>
    workspace.openModel(model)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nl4py/NetLogoHeadlessWorkspace.py", line 52, in openModel
    self.__bridge.openModel(self.__session,self.__path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1286, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling t.openModel.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.nlogo.headless.HeadlessWorkspace.open(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at nl4py.server.HeadlessWorkspaceController.openModel(HeadlessWorkspaceController.java:133)
    at nl4py.server.NetLogoControllerServer.openModel(NetLogoControllerServer.java:100)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```

Answer (score 3):

Wow I literally wanted to give up and decided to try a different NetLogo version and it WORKED. So for anyone having the same/similar issue try running it on NL 6.0.4 or older. They changed some directories in the newest version so it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for bringing up this issue! There was a change in the NetLogo Controlling API with NetLogo 6.1.0 to the `HeadlessWorkspace.open(...)` method, which caused a compatibility issue with NL4Py. More information on this issue can be found [here](https://github.com/chathika/NL4Py/issues/8).

I've released a fix for this in version [`0.5.2`](https://pypi.org/project/NL4Py/0.5.2/) such that both NetLogo 6.0 and NetLogo 6.1 should be supported now.

Please, `pip install --upgrade nl4py`. Do let me know if the issue persists. Thanks!